# Trying to change the value of text on a label when on_press is called for a function

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

Can't figure out after three days on how to press the Next Button and a random word from a list appears for the text in label widget for sight_word.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class SightWord(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SightWordApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SightWord()

# Function that selects random sight word from list
    def sight_word(self):
        word_list = ['What', 'How', 'My', 'Know', 'You']
        random_index = randrange(0,len(word_list))
        word = word_list[random_index]
        print(word)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SightWordApp().run()
```

Kivy File:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<SightWord>:

    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: root.width * 0.01, root.height * 0.01

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Label:
            id: sight_word
            # This is where I want the word to change values
            text: 'XXXX'
            size_hint: 1, None
            font_size: '100sp'
            height: self.texture_size[1] + (2 * root.padding[1])

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Button:
            id: next_btn
            text: 'Next'
            on_press: app.sight_word()
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.texture_size[1] + (4 * root.padding[1])
            width: self.texture_size[1] + (4 * root.padding[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, you only need to locate the right object (`Label`) and pass a value to its `text` property. I see you've already made an `id` for the label, and you call it via `app`, so let's use that:

**.kv**

```
Button:
    id: next_btn
    text: 'Next'
    on_press: app.sight_word(sight_word)  # pass id to a function
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: self.texture_size[1] + (4 * root.padding[1])
    width: self.texture_size[1] + (4 * root.padding[1])
```

**.py**

```
    def sight_word(self, label):  # use the id/object
        word_list = ['What', 'How', 'My', 'Know', 'You']
        random_index = randrange(0,len(word_list))
        word = word_list[random_index]
        label.text = word  # change text property to your string
```

Comment: As you can tell, I am new this kivy.  I knew it was something easy I was missing.  Thank you very much.  It works.